# Removing arrays from other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assume that I have this array:

```
a = [
    [2823832908, 10071920], 
    [5384625228, 10924221], 
    [8488934028, 313411415], 
    [2823828588, 10071580], 
    [5224682868, 14919881], 
    [8155986228, 560217208], 
    [3458951628, 10071570], 
    [6382592388, 25064430], 
    [5021452668, 10924221], 
    [8827673748, 59397160], 
    [8647215588, 26343621]
]
```

and this array:

```
b = [
    [8488934028, 313411415], 
    [8647215588, 26343621]
]
```

How can I get a new array that contains the values in array `a` that are not in array `b`, or how can I  remove the values in array `b` from array `a`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: Do you consider a tuple to be a single value?

Comment: use regular expressions and Array.prototype.splice might help as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an empty result array.
2. Iterate over `a`, select its current element i.e. `[2823832908, 10071920]`
3. Compare current element for equality against each element of b , to compare equality
   you can use JSON.stringify or  .join to create string representation of arrays.
4. If the current element does not match any element of `b`, appent it to result array.
5. Repeat.

> ```
>   a = [
>                 [2823832908, 10071920], 
>                 [5384625228, 10924221], 
>                 [8488934028, 313411415], 
>                 [2823828588, 10071580], 
>                 [5224682868, 14919881], 
>                 [8155986228, 560217208], 
>                 [3458951628, 10071570], 
>                 [6382592388, 25064430], 
>                 [5021452668, 10924221], 
>                 [8827673748, 59397160], 
>                 [8647215588, 26343621]
> ];
> ```

```
    b = [
        [8488934028, 313411415], 
        [8647215588, 26343621]
    ]; 


    var result = [];
    a.forEach(
        function(elem,idx,arr)
        {
            var sig = JSON.stringify(elem);
            var match = false;
            for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++)
            {
                if(sig == JSON.stringify(b[i]))
                   {
                     match = true;
                     break;
                   }
            }
            if(match === false)
                {
                    result.push(elem);
                }
        }
        );

     console.log(result);
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/Ag39M/4/

Comment: This is a good answer, but it's worth noting that `JSON.stringify` is not a great way to compare arrays. [See the comparison in our methods' performance for why](http://jsperf.com/filtering-arrays).

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks for the performance analysis. Yes,the OP can use more optimized methods to compare the arrays. I used JSON.stringify assuming smaller inputs and its simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, principally because two arrays are not equal in Javascript, even if they have exactly the same keys.

You have to compare them manually, for example with [this function by Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837725/417562).

You will then have to loop through the values in first array and compare them to every value in the second array.

The code might look like this:

```
var filtered = [];

// loop through every element in a
a.forEach(function(elA) {
    // loop through every element in b
    // if the elA is identical to any elB, some will immediately return true
    // if elA is not identical to any elB, it will return false
    var found = a.some(function(elB) {
        return arraysIdentical(elA, elB);
    });

    // if we didn't find any equal ones, we'll add elA to the filtered array
    if (!found) {
        filtered.push(elA);
    }
});
```

Note that this relies upon [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). If you need to support older browsers, you'll need to shim them, with the polyfill code in those links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation using [undescore.js](http://underscorejs.org).

```
function diff(a1, a2) {
  return _.filter(a1, function(e1) {
    return !_.some(a2, function(e2) {
      return _.isEqual(e1, e2);
    });
  });
}
```

Example:

```
var a = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, 7 ], [ 8 ], [ 9 ] ];
var b = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 8 ], [ 9 ] ];

console.log(diff(a, b));
// [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, 7 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function arra_diff(a, b)
{
  var arr=[], diff=[];
  for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    arr[a[i]]=true;
  for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    if(arr[b[i]]) delete arr[b[i]];
    else arr[b[i]]=true;
  for(var k in arr)
    diff.push(k);
  return diff;
}
```

or

```
function arra_diff(d, c) { /* d=a,c=b */
    for (var b = [], e = [], a = 0; a < d.length; a++) {
        b[d[a]] = !0;
    }
    for (a = 0; a < c.length; a++) {
        b[c[a]] ? delete b[c[a]] : b[c[a]] = !0;
    }
    for (var f in b) {
        e.push(f);
    }
    return e;
};
```

Comment: I've voted this down not because it's wrong but because it's unreadable and uncommented and is therefore not a good StackOverflow answer.